# Campos en blanco en select generado dinámicamente

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código el cual genera un `select` con varios `option` cuya información viene de base de datos:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'              => array( 'centros' ),
        'posts_per_page'         => -1,
        'post_status'            => array( 'publish' )
        );

$query = new WP_Query($args);

echo '<select id="nombre_centro">';
while ($query->have_posts()): 
    $query->the_post();
    echo '<option >'. get_field('nombre_centro').'<option>' ;
endwhile;
echo ' </select>';
```

El problema es que existe un espacio en blanco entre cada uno de ellos como se muestra en la imagen y no encuentro la razón.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Explora el código fuente que se está produciendo. Si es posible, compártenos un trozo del mismo, donde está ese `select`...

Comment: Prueba de este modo: `echo '<option >'. get_field('nombre_centro',false,false).'<option>' ;` Puede que te esté trayendo el dato con formato, y éste incluya un salto de línea. [Ver aquí](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) (in fine).

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que no estás cerrando la etiqueta `option` y al contrario de eso estás insertando otra, por lo que el navegador está cerrando ambas etiquetas automáticamente pero la segunda de ellas no contiene información, es por eso que se ve como un espacio en blanco.

```php
$args = array(
        'post_type'              => array( 'centros' ),
        'posts_per_page'         => -1,
        'post_status'            => array( 'publish' )
        );

$query = new WP_Query($args);

echo '<select id="nombre_centro">';
while ($query->have_posts()): 
    $query->the_post();
    # echo '<option>'. get_field('nombre_centro').'<option>';
    #                                             ~~~~~~~~~~
    # Salida: <option>nombre centro</option><option></option>
    echo '<option>'. get_field('nombre_centro').'</option>';
    # Salida: <option>nombre centro</option>
endwhile;
echo ' </select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type'              => array( 'centros' ),
            'posts_per_page'         => -1,
            'post_status'            => array( 'publish' )
            );
    
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    
    echo '<select id="nombre_centro">';
    while ($query->have_posts()): 
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<option >'. rtrim(ltrim(get_field('nombre_centro'))).'</option>' ;
    endwhile;
    echo ' </select>';
```

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.rtrim.php

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ltrim.php

Comment: Seria buena idea agregaras que realizan las funciones y como ayuda a corregir el problema planteado, para que sea de ayuda tu respuesta a más miembros de la comunidad.